# If $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int_x^{\infty} |f(t)|^pdt=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

If $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int_x^{\infty} |f(t)|^pdt=0$ where $ p \in (1,\infty)$

I tried to use this [Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837624/show-that-if-int-a-inftyft-dt-converges-then-lim-x-to-infty-int-x) but if $x\to\infty$, also $a\to\infty$, so $\int_a^{\infty}|f(t)|^p dt$ is not a constant. So, I can no longer find how to proceed by any other means, could you help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty \implies \int^{\infty}_{n} |f(x)| dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939621/int-mathbb-r-fx-dx-infty-implies-int-infty-n-fx-dx-to-0)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you wrote   $\int_x^{\infty} |f(x)|^{p}dx$  for $\int_x^{\infty} |f(t)|^{p}dt$.

This is an immediate consequenca of DCT. $I_{(a,\infty)} |f(x)|^{p}$ tends to $0$ at every point and it is dominated by the integrable function $|f|^{p}$. Hence its integral tends to $0$.